# Значение выражения в скобочках после тела функции JS

Tags: javascript

Сегодня, осваивая JS, заметил вот такой кусок кода:

```
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" src="', e.target.result, '" />'].join('');
        document.getElementById('output').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
})(f);
```

Конкретно меня заинтересовала последняя строчка, где после параметров функции .onload передаётся переменная в отдельных скобочках. Объясните, пожалуйста, для чего она нужна и как это работает, ибо без неё скрипт не выполняется

Comment: в етом примере в reader.onload присваиваеться выражение, которое обернуто в скобки, что заставляет его сразу выполниться, в свою очередь выражение возвращает функцию,которая принимает 1н параметр, и етими загадачными скобками в конце мы функцию ету и вызываем, передавая в нее параметр f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это самовызывающаяся функция.

Главной идеей является то, что анонимная функция вызывается сразу после своего объявления. Преимущество от использования самовызывающихся функций вы получите, если нужно выполнить код один раз и сохранить его резульататы во "внешней среде" (без объявления глобальных переменных).

Например, для небольшой веб-страницы можно написать обработчики событий для элементов на странице. Самовызывающиеся функции подходящее средство для такой ситуации.

В данном случае значение в скобках - аргумент `theFile`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь и сам увидел

Comment: Стоит перенести суть статьи по ссылке прямо в ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash сделано)